# UnicodeEncodeError while executing Python code on QGIS 2.6.1

Tags: python, qgis-plugins, qgis-2, qswat, unicodeencodeerror

I have installed the plugin QSWAT and created a new project, and what is happening now is the error below.

What can be the problem? I've already tried to install different versions of Python and different versions of QGIS. What can be the problem?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/etarn/.qgis2/python/plugins\QSWAT\qswat.py", line 174, in run
    self.setupProject(proj, False)
  File "C:/Users/etarn/.qgis2/python/plugins\QSWAT\qswat.py", line 241, in setupProject
    self._gv = GlobalVars(isBatch)
  File "C:/Users/etarn/.qgis2/python/plugins\QSWAT\globals.py", line 187, in __init__
    self.db = DBUtils(self.projDir, self.projName, self.dbProjTemplate, self.dbRefTemplate, self.isBatch)
  File "C:/Users/etarn/.qgis2/python/plugins\QSWAT\DBUtils.py", line 58, in __init__
    self.updateProjDb(Parameters._SWATEDITORVERSION)
  File "C:/Users/etarn/.qgis2/python/plugins\QSWAT\DBUtils.py", line 253, in updateProjDb
    QSWATUtils.error('Could not update table in project database {0}: {1}'.format(self.dbFile, traceback.format_exc()), self.isBatch)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u0141' in position 7: ordinal not in range(128)


Python version:
2.7.4 (default, Apr  6 2013, 19:54:46) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]


QGIS version:
2.6.1-Brighton Brighton, e2a51df

Python path: ['C:/PROGRA~2/QGISBR~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\\processing', 'C:/PROGRA~2/QGISBR~1/apps/qgis/./python', u'C:/Users/etarn/.qgis2/python', u'C:/Users/etarn/.qgis2/python/plugins', 'C:/PROGRA~2/QGISBR~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins', 'C:\\PROGRA~2\\QGISBR~1\\bin\\python27.zip', 'C:\\PROGRA~2\\QGISBR~1\\apps\\Python27\\DLLs', 'C:\\PROGRA~2\\QGISBR~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib', 'C:\\PROGRA~2\\QGISBR~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\plat-win', 'C:\\PROGRA~2\\QGISBR~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\lib-tk', 'C:\\PROGRA~2\\QGISBR~1\\bin', 'C:\\PROGRA~2\\QGISBR~1\\apps\\Python27', 'C:\\PROGRA~2\\QGISBR~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\PROGRA~2\\QGISBR~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\PIL', 'C:\\PROGRA~2\\QGISBR~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\jinja2-2.7.2-py2.7.egg', 'C:\\PROGRA~2\\QGISBR~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\markupsafe-0.23-py2.7-win32.egg', 'C:\\PROGRA~2\\QGISBR~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\python_dateutil-2.2-py2.7.egg', 'C:\\PROGRA~2\\QGISBR~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\pytz-2014.2-py2.7.egg', 'C:\\PROGRA~2\\QGISBR~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\win32', 'C:\\PROGRA~2\\QGISBR~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib', 'C:\\PROGRA~2\\QGISBR~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin', 'C:\\PROGRA~2\\QGISBR~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\Shapely-1.2.18-py2.7-win32.egg', 'C:\\PROGRA~2\\QGISBR~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\six-1.6.1-py2.7.egg', 'C:\\PROGRA~2\\QGISBR~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\wx-2.8-msw-unicode', 'C:\\PROGRA~2\\QGISBR~1\\apps\\qgis\\python\\plugins\\fTools\\tools', 'D:/ET/K\xc5\x81ODAWA/GIS/SWAT']
```

Comment: Why not download QSWAT3 v1.6.5 for QGIS 3? Because QGIS 2 is no longer supported, it is recommended to use QSWAT3 for QGIS 3 Ref.: https://swat.tamu.edu/software/qswat/

Comment: Is the unicode error just a red herring or do you have this letter "Latin Capital Letter L with Stroke" https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+0141 in some name?